# How to use a callback when returning false/true in clientside events (Web Forms)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, webforms, asp-classic

If I have:

```
<asp:Button ID="someId" runat="server" Text="Some Text" OnClientClick="return HandleThis();" />
```

With the javascript:

```
function HandleThis() {
    return false;
}
```

It will work perfectly.

But what happened if the result of my client validation come from a callback (an ajax result for example):

```
<asp:Button ID="someId" runat="server" Text="Some Text" OnClientClick="return HandleThis();" />
```

And the client side validation:

```
function HandleThis() {
    executeSomeValidation(function (result) {
            console.log(result);
            return result;
        });
}

function executeSomeValidation(){
    setTimeout(function () {
                    callback(true);
                }, 10000);
}
```

How can i get it to work?

Comment: What do you want to accomplish with this? The result from the function i mean. BTW, your executeSomeValidation function should probably take "callback" as a parameter?

Comment: @Arg0n I need a pre validation (everything in clientside), before the postpack (reach event handler in aspx.vb). My pre validation use a modal dialog and wait for an user response.
Many times I used validation in client side without waiting for anything (like first example) and works fine but now I need to wait.

Comment: This is absolutely not asp-classic.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent a PostBack based on some external resource, you might want to do something like this:

JavaScript:

```
var allowPostback = false;

function HandleThis() {
    if(!allowPostback){
        executeSomeValidation(function (result) {
            console.log(result);
            allowPostback = result;
            if(allowPostback) {
                document.getElementById("<%=someId.ClientId%>").click();
            }
        });
    }

    return allowPostback;
}

function executeSomeValidation(callback){
    setTimeout(function () {
        callback(true);
    }, 10000);
}
```

It will prevent the PostBack at first, but click the button again after the resource has loaded (If result is true). Code is not tested.